# AlertDialog de Evaluacion en APP Android

Tags: java, android, alertdialog

Estimado Amigos, tengo una duda, actualmente en mi app tengo un alertdialog para evaluar mi aplicación en google play, actualmente ejecuto ese alertdialog pasado 3 minutos dentro de la app pero creo que no es lo optimo ¿cual es el criterio para que este alertdialog se abra automáticamente en la app?¿cada ciertas aperturas de la app?¿que código usan para hacer esto?, tengo una función que llama a Calificanos(); y lo abre a los 3 minutos de estar en la app.

mi código es el siguiente:

```
public void Calificanos(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Califica Nuestra APP!!");
    alert.setMessage("Nos serviría de mucho que nos des 5 estrellas, así podremos seguir brindándote la mejor experiencia en el rastreo de tus paquetes Aliexpress");
    alert.setPositiveButton("Claro que si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Gracias :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //*************** Ejecuta URL para evaluar *******************//
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("LA URL DE MI APP");)
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
            //************************************************************//
        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("Mas tarde :(", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"De Igual forma te agradecemos por usar nuestra APP :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    alert.create().show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostar un cuadro de diálogo para calificar nuestra app sería parecido a mostrar un anuncio insterticial, al fin y al cabo es publicidad. Por tanto te recomiendo utlizar las mismas prácticas para mostrar el cuadro de diálogo que utilizarías si implementases anuncios intersticiales.

*Google recomienda:*

> Si su aplicación es un juego con diferentes niveles o fases, considere la posibilidad de colocar un anuncio intersticial entre una o varias de dichas fases. El paso de un nivel a otro procura una pausa natural para el usuario que le permite ver el anuncio intersticial adecuadamente. Si su aplicación no es un juego pero tiene muchas páginas o secciones, valore la posibilidad de colocar un anuncio intersticial cuando se hayan pasado una serie de pantallas o se hayan realizado una serie de acciones. Evite colocarlo cada vez que el usuario haga algo.

Lo mejor es implementar el `AlertDialog` inicialmente y luego ir valorando la actividad de los usuarios, comprobar su efectividad e ir cambiandolo hasta llegar a lo que queremos, cuidando siempre nuestra experiencia de usuario.

Para verificar si ya el usuario ha calificado la aplicación puedes usar la clase `SharedPreferences`.
El inconveniente al utilizar esta solución es que no vas a tener la certeza de si el usuario valoró o no la app, solo vas a saber si pulsó el botón de calificar, lo que haga de ahi en adelante ya esta afuera del alcance de tu app.

```
alert.setPositiveButton("Claro que si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
       ...
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("is_qualify", true);
            editor.apply();
    }
});
```

Luego, donde llamas al método `Calificanos()` recuperas el valor de tu preferencia y decides si mostrar o no el diálogo.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if (!preferences.getBoolean("is_qualify", false)){
    Calificanos();
}
```

Comment: Me parece una buena respuesta pero si lo pone cada ciertas pantallas como sabria si el usuario ya lo califico antes? este cuadro de dialogo segiria molestando y seria algo muy fastidioso, tienes alguna recomendacion, para solventar eso

Comment: @crazyProgrammer estaba investigando alguna forma de saber si la app fue valorada o no, pero no encontré nada útil, pero voy a seguir investigando y si encuentro una solución mejor la comparto contigo. Edité la respuesta con una solución.